# Not any receiving Email all the things going fine

Tags: php, email, infusionsoft

I am using PHP iSDK API for sending email.
This is my email sending file.

```
<?php
echo "Hello World! <br/>";
include('iSDK/src/isdk.php');
$myApp = new iSDK();
if ($myApp->cfgCon("connectionName")){
   echo "Connected...";
}else{
   echo "Not Connected...";
}

$myApp->sendEmail('conList','hassan.nazir.786@gmail.com','kamran_asadi15@yahoo.com', 'ccAddresses', 'bccAddresses', 'contentType', 'subject', 'htmlBody', 'txtBody');
?>
```

This is other .conf page.

```
<?php

$connInfo = array('connectionName:infusionsoft.com:i:APIKEYGOESHERE:This is the connection for applicationName.infusionsoft.com');

?>
```

But I am not getting any email, what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @OP might be a good idea to take out email addresses and things like that from your sample. Probably not an issue but just in case.

Comment: Try checking the mail server logs on your server they will tell you if anything is actually being sent. Whilst I have not used the library you are using, You do not appear to be checking for any return value. does it return anything to indicate success / failure?

Comment: what did you say I dint get.

Comment: it is not indicating any thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to send email using infusionsoft api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733070/how-to-send-email-using-infusionsoft-api)